# Scrapy throwing up Traceback when trying to parse tabulated data

Tags: python, scrapy

I am running Scrapy.org version 2.7 64 bit on Windows Vista 64 bit. I have some Scrapy code that is trying parse data contained within a table at the URL contained within the following code:

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.utils.markup import remove_tags
from scrapy.cmdline import execute
import re


class MySpider(Spider):
    name = "wiki"
    allowed_domains = ["whoscored.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.whoscored.com/Players/3859/Fixtures/Wayne-Rooney"]

def parse(self, response):

    for row in response.selector.xpath('//table[@id="player-fixture"]//tr[td[@class="tournament"]]'):
    # Is this row contains goal symbols?
        list_of_goals = row.xpath('//span[@title="Goal"')
        if list_of_goals:
            print remove_tags(list_of_goals).encode('utf-8')     

execute(['scrapy','crawl','wiki'])
```

However, it is throwing up the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 1201, in mainLoop
    self.runUntilCurrent()
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 824, in runUntilCurrent
    call.func(*call.args, **call.kw)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 383, in callback
    self._startRunCallbacks(result)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 491, in _startRunCallbacks
    self._runCallbacks()
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 578, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spider.py", line 56, in parse
    raise NotImplementedError
exceptions.NotImplementedError:
```

Can anyone tell me what the issue is here? I am trying to get a screen print of all items in the table, including the data in the goals and assists column.

Thanks

Comment: what version of scrapy are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your indentation is wrong:

```
class MySpider(Spider):
    name = "wiki"
    allowed_domains = ["whoscored.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.whoscored.com/Players/3859/Fixtures/Wayne-Rooney"]

    def parse(self, response):

        for row in response.selector.xpath('//table[@id="player-fixture"]//tr[td[@class="tournament"]]'):
        # Is this row contains goal symbols?
            list_of_goals = row.xpath('//span[@title="Goal"')
            if list_of_goals:
                print remove_tags(list_of_goals).encode('utf-8')
```

Implementing a `parse` method is a requirement when you use the `Spider class`, this is what the method is like in the source code:

```
def parse(self, response):
        raise NotImplementedError
```

Your indentation was wrong so parse was not part of the class and therefore you had not implemented the required method.

The `raise NotImplementedError` is there to ensure you write the required  `parse` method when inheriting from the `Spider` base class.

You now just have to find the correct `xpath` ;)

Comment: that is throwing up a traceback of 'File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 578, in _runCallbacks
     current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
   File "C:\Python27\missing\missing\spiders\test2.py", line 61, in parse
     list_of_goals = row.xpath('//span[@title="Goal"')
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\selector\unified.py", line 98, in xpath
     raise ValueError("Invalid XPath: %s" % query)
 exceptions.ValueError: Invalid XPath: //span[@title="Goal"' thanks

Comment: yep, that is another question! You have the wrong xpath.

Comment: No worries, if you have no luck I will have a look tomorrow. Time for sleep here

Comment: No worries, your first path seems correct it must be `('//span[@title="Goal"')` that is the problem.Ciao

Comment: the above example was missing a closed bracket. it nor runs without producing an error, however does not return any of the desired date. i have asked a subsequent question at the link to follow asking for the correct syntax to get a result, but i dont seem to be getting anywhere:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24736336/xpath-method-not-returning-results-using-scrapy/24737120?noredirect=1#comment38376463_24737120