# Xpath() method not returning results using Scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am using Python.org version 2.7 64 bit on Windows Vista 64 bit. I have some Scrapy code that is attempting to parse the table at this link headed 'Wayne Rooney's Match History:"...

http://www.whoscored.com/Players/3859/Fixtures/Wayne-Rooney
The code I have so far is this:

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.utils.markup import remove_tags
from scrapy.cmdline import execute
import re


class MySpider(Spider):
    name = "wiki"
    allowed_domains = ["whoscored.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.whoscored.com/Players/3859/Fixtures/Wayne-Rooney"]

    def parse(self, response):

        for row in response.selector.xpath('//table[@id="player-fixture"]//tr[td[@class="tournament"]]'):
        # Is this row contains goal symbols?
            list_of_goals = row.xpath('//span[@title="Goal"]')
            if list_of_goals:
                list = str(list_of_goals)
                print remove_tags(list).encode('utf-8')     

execute(['scrapy','crawl','wiki'])
```

This returns all the data from the table apart from the goal data (it doesn't return assists either, but I haven't added any logic for that yet. This code is a development of the original piece of code I had which did not return goals or assists either:

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.utils.markup import remove_tags
from scrapy.cmdline import execute
import re


class MySpider(Spider):
    name = "goal"
    allowed_domains = ["whoscored.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.whoscored.com/Players/3859/Fixtures/Wayne-Rooney"]    

    def parse(self, response):
        titles = response.selector.xpath("normalize-space(//title)")
        for titles in titles:
            body = response.xpath('//table[@id="player-fixture"]//tr[td[@class="tournament"]]').extract()
            body2 = "".join(body)

            print remove_tags(body2).encode('utf-8')

execute(['scrapy','crawl','goal'])
```

The statement in the HTML source that indicates a goal is this:

```
<span class="incident-wrapper"><span class="incidents-icon ui-icon goal" title="Goal"></span></span>
```

Can anyone tell me why my code listed at the top does not return goals scored with that logic? is it something to do with the fact that a ball icon is used to denote goals rather than a word?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In first version you get only `<span class="incidents-icon ui-icon goal" title="Goal"></span>` and there is no text so you get empty string as result - because you `remove_tags()`.

---

Adding string "GOAL" for rows with  "goal icon":

```
list_of_goals = row.xpath('//span[@title="Goal"]')

if list_of_goals:        
    list = str(list_of_goals)
    print remove_tags(list).encode('utf-8') + "GOAL" # <-- string
```

or (becasue there is no text in `<span title="Goal">` )

```
list_of_goals = row.xpath('//span[@title="Goal"]')

if list_of_goals:
    print "GOAL" # <-- string
```

---

**EDIT:**

I made my version with [Scrapy 0.22.2](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.22/index.html).

Probably we use differrent version of Scrapy because some your functions did't work for me.

I prefer `css` selectors then `xpath` - they are simpler for me.

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.cmdline import execute


class MySpider(Spider):

    name = "goal"
    allowed_domains = ["whoscored.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.whoscored.com/Players/3859/Fixtures/Wayne-Rooney"]    

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)

        #titles = sel.xpath("normalize-space(//title)")
        #print 'titles:', titles.extract()[0]
        print
        print 'titles:', "".join( sel.css("title::text").extract() ).strip()
        print

        #rows = sel.xpath('//table[@id="player-fixture"]//tbody//tr')
        rows = sel.css('table#player-fixture tbody tr')

        for row in rows:
            #print 'date:', row.xpath('.//td[@class="date"]/text()').extract()
            #print 'result:', row.xpath('.//td[@class="result"]/a/text()').extract()
            print 'date:', "".join( row.css('.date::text').extract() ).strip()
            print 'result:', "".join( row.css('.result a::text').extract() ).strip()
            print 'team_home:', "".join( row.css('.team.home a::text').extract() ).strip()
            print 'team_away:', "".join( row.css('.team.away a::text').extract() ).strip()
            print 'info:', "".join( row.css('.info::text').extract() ).strip(), "".join( row.css('.info::attr(title)').extract() ).strip()
            print 'rating:', "".join( row.css('.rating::text').extract() ).strip()
            print 'incidents:', ", ".join( row.css('.incidents-icon::attr(title)').extract() ).strip()
            print '-'*40

#execute(['scrapy','crawl','goal'])
execute(['scrapy','runspider','main.py'])
```

and part of result

```
titles: Wayne Rooney Match History | WhoScored.com

date: 17-08-2013
result: 1 : 4
team_home: Swansea
team_away: Manchester United
info: 28' Minutes played in this match
rating: 7.26
incidents: Assist, Assist
----------------------------------------
date: 26-08-2013
result: 0 : 0
team_home: Manchester United
team_away: Chelsea
info: 90' Minutes played in this match
rating: 7.03
incidents: 
----------------------------------------
date: 14-09-2013
result: 2 : 0
team_home: Manchester United
team_away: Crystal Palace
info: 90' Minutes played in this match
rating: 8.44
incidents: Man of the Match, Goal
----------------------------------------
date: 17-09-2013
result: 4 : 2
team_home: Manchester United
team_away: Bayer Leverkusen
info: 84' Minutes played in this match
rating: 9.18
incidents: Goal, Goal, Assist
----------------------------------------
date: 22-09-2013
result: 4 : 1
team_home: Manchester City
team_away: Manchester United
info: 90' Minutes played in this match
rating: 7.17
incidents: Goal, Yellow Card
----------------------------------------
date: 25-09-2013
result: 1 : 0
team_home: Manchester United
team_away: Liverpool
info: 90' Minutes played in this match
rating: 
incidents: Man of the Match, Assist
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: i have tried printing a string without removing the tags and also tried just printing 'list_of_goals' each returns a result per row like this when printed in the python IDLE: 'EPL,14-09-2013'Manchester United,2 : 0,Crystal Palace,90,'8.44' (commas added by me)...

Comment: all the data represented by icons rather than plain text are still not being returned.

Comment: i have also tried the following logic and still got no goal data printed to screen: 'list_of_goals = row.xpath('//span[@class="incident-wrapper"]//span[@class="incidents-icon ui-icon goal"]//span[@title="Goal"]')'

Comment: Data represented by icon is empty string so you can't get any results from `<span>` - all text are outside that `<span>` - forget `<span>`.

Comment: Eventually you can add own string "Goal" to results when you find '<span title="Goal">'.

Comment: im not sure what you mean. can you give me some example syntax?

Comment: so if i want it so that goals are scored in with the rest of my data? at the minute im just getting a list at the end of the output.#

Comment: btw your example returns "GOAL" for every row in the table rather than just the ones where the relevant span tag is found.

Comment: I made full working version - see answer - I use Scrapy 0.22.2

Comment: that is almost a perfect answer, except that it is not returning any man of the match performances under incidents, as denoted by a star in the table on the page. thanks

Comment: im guessing this is because of the slightly different way this is coded in the html

Comment: Oh, yes. I forgot this column :)

Comment: ive tried this "".join(row.css('.incidents-icon ui-icon mom span::attr(title)').extract() ).strip() + ',' which does not error but not produce an output

Comment: ive added the comma on the end btw

Comment: BTW: I add comma in `", ".join(...)`

Comment: ok great, that worked fine. thanks. im assuming you are using incident-icon now rather than incident-wrapper because this is being used in all of the icons in the source code, whereas incident-wrapper is not?

Comment: yes, I used `incident-icon` to get all values in one line of code.